# Changing workspace in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've been using Eclipse to code in Java for a while now. For the workspace, I've been using the default option that Eclipse gives. If I switched workspaces now, will the projects I currently have saved in Eclipse move over to the new workspace I switch to?

Comment: IMO this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180474/how-to-move-an-eclipse-helios-project-to-a-different-workspace

Comment: The new workspace will be empty. You can have as many workspaces as you like and switch between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They won't. But you can always use File > Import to clone or link projects from another workspace.